# How to extend a facebook long lived (still valid about to expire) token?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token

How can I extend a facebook long lived (still valid about to expire) token on Android platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend a token, call `extendAccessTokenIfNeeded` to extend the current access token.  However, this only works if the user has the native Facebook for Android app installed.  If the user does not have the native Facebook app installed, our SDK currently does not support extending access tokens.

To do it manually, you have to write your own networking code to issue a request to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id=APP_ID& client_secret=APP_SECRET& grant_type=fb_exchange_token& fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

and parse the response for the new access token.

Our documentation for this issue is found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#extend_token